# Select all buttons in my form one by one using for loop-- eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have five buttons in my form with names buttonDo,buttonStop,buttonPause,buttonPlay,buttonselect. How to I select all the buttons on by one in for loop to check some condition. I need to a code where it finds total no of buttons on its own and keeps incrementing on its own till it finds the last button.
Plz help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Try with that code, the first function start iterate, the second ( called from the first ) walk through the View three and find all possible instance of Button

```
public ArrayList<Button> getButtons() {
    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    findButtons(viewGroup, buttons);
    return buttons;
}

private static void findButtons(ViewGroup viewGroup,ArrayList<Button> buttons) {
    for (int i = 0, N = viewGroup.getChildCount(); i < N; i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            findButtons((ViewGroup) child, buttons);
        } else if (child instanceof Button) {
            buttons.add((Button) child);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that help!

Comment: can you plz help me with this

Answer (score 1):

In this case ll is a LinearLayout and this search is only inside this one layout and will not recursively search the whole view tree. Something like this probably works. Did not test.

```
Vector<Button> buttons = new Vector<Button>();

for (int i=0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++){
    View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof Button) {
        buttons.add(v);
    }
}

Button lastButton = buttons.lastElement();
```

I have to say it sounds like you are probably approaching the problem in a wrong way. This sounds like a very strange approach. Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve?